# Is this a partial ordering on $X$?

Tags: order-theory

$X=Z^2$, $(n_1,n_2)<_{lex} (m_1,m_2)$ if $n_1<m_1$ or $[n_1=m_1$ and $n_2<m_2]$

I think not because its not reflexive.  Is this correct?

Similarly, $X=R_{>0}$ (positive reals), $x ≪ y$ if and only if $\frac{y}{x} >10$.
Again, this looks like a partial ordering, but I don't think its reflexive.

Comment: Lexicographic ordering: $(a,b)\leq_{\rm lex} (c,d)$ if $a\leq c$ or ($a=c$ and $b\leq d$).

Comment: @Wuestenfux the homework question just has less than.  Does this make it not a partial ordering?

Comment: The lex ordering is a partial ordering. Its actually total (dictionary order).

Comment: @Wuestenfux  what about the fact that $(n,m) <_{lex} (n,m)$?  Doesn't that mean it isn't reflexive and therefore not a partial ordering?

Comment: Its reflective $(a,b)\leq_{\rm lex}(a,b)$ since $a=a$ and $b\leq b$. Second case.

Comment: @Wuestenfux but it isn't less than or equal to, its just less than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) (and several books), there are two definitions of partial order, depending if it is strict or non-strict.

A *non-strict* partial order is a binary relation that is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric. A *strict* partial order is a binary relation that is irreflexive and transitive (which implies asymmetry as well). Strict and non-strict partial orders are closely related:

1. If $<$ is a strict partial order, the non-strict partial order $\leq$ 
   induced by $<$ is just the reflexive closure of $<$, i.e. $a \leq b$ iff $a < 
    b$ or $a = b$;
2. If $\leq$ is a non-strict partial order, the strict partial order $<$ 
   induced by $\leq$ is just the irreflexive kernel of $\leq$, i.e. $a < b$ iff $a 
   \leq b$ and $a \neq b$.

Concerning your question, $<_{leq}$ and $≪$ are *strict* partial orders (and hence they are not non-strict since they are irreflexive).

**Supplementary question:** Can you show me a relation which is both reflexive and irreflexive?

Comment: Yes, the empty relation is both reflective, irreflective and many other things.  Here is a riddle for you.  What unique topological space has exactly one open set?